# C# timer event to update datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timer

I am trying to create a "dashboard" form with a text box and datagridview. The data loaded into them comes from an excel spreadsheet that is updated every 10 minutes. I added a timer to refresh the data but can't get the textbox and the datagridview on the form to update. I can tell the timer is working because the form WILL update if I scroll down to the bottom of the datagridview. What am I missing?

```
        public AllOrders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        Get_Data();
    }
    private void Get_Data()
    {
        // connect to get file
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\\\xxxxx\\labdash.xls';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\";";
        OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        // select only worksheet in spreadsheet
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
        // define dataset as entire spreadsheet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        // define view to set filters, restrictions, etc
        DataView dv;
        dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0], "ordept = 'CHE'", "ordept", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        // define header information
        ctr = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        textBox1.Text = ctr.ToString() + "  outstanding tests";
        upddte = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        updtim = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = upddte.Substring(5, 2) + "  last updated";
        // hide columns not needed
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[17].Visible = false;
        // sort by priority, specimen date, specimen time
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[13], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[14], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        // change font color for certain status'
        dataGridView1.RowPrePaint
            += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowPrePaint);
        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        textBox1.Update();
        textBox1.Refresh();
        textBox2.Update();
        textBox2.Refresh();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Get_Data();
    }
```

Comment: You should add your timer to the form itself. Currently you have it only as local variable in the constructor, so it might get destroyed at any time by the garbage collector.

Comment: I thought adding a timer from the Visual Studio toolbox was adding it to the form itself.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your form class is named `AllOrders`. The constructor:

```
public AllOrders()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    ...
}
```

What happens to timer1 at the end of your constructor? Is there anyone who holds a reference to the timer object? What will the garbage collector do?

Your Timer is a Component. Your Form can contain many Components, but you must keep them alive until you are certain that you don't need them anymore. The Timer is also IDisposable, you should Dispose it when your form is Disposed.

The easy way for any Component to do this, is to add the Component to your `Form.Components`. See the code of your Form Dispose, just above your Form's InitializeComponent.

You can add the Timer using your visual studio designer. It's in the Toolbox under Components.
If you want to add it manually, make sure that it stays alive after the constructor, and add it to this.Components, so you know that it will be disposed when your form is disposed.

```
class Allorders : Form
{
    private readonly Timer timer1;

    public AllOrders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.timer1 = new Timer();
        this.components.Add(this.timer1);
        ... // other timer initializations
    }
}
```

The code to Dispose this.components is already in your form.Dispose
Depending on what other conrols you have added to your form, `this.components` is null. In  that case you must create it yourself:

```
InitializeComponent();

if (this.components == null)
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.timer1 = new Timer();
this.components.Add(this.timer1);
```

Comment: I believe I understand what a component is (items I've added from the Visual Studio toolbox like text boxes and the timer).  I just don't understand what else I would have to do to it if these items were added from the toolbox.  I would have thought everything it needed would be added in the correct place.  So you're saying I have to add more to the code so it won't be destroyed at some unknown point in the process?
I had added the 5 "timer" lines after the Initialize line because I saw those in another solution.  But they don't seem to make it work either.

Comment: Indeed, if you added a Control using the Toolbox, then you seldom have to do something yourself. You can see the created code in `InitializeComponents`. You can see that a field is created to keep your Component alive until destruction. Your error was that you forgot to save your timer outside your constructor. Some people like to add Controls themselves by typing the code. In that case you add them as a member or property to your class and create the Control in the constructor after the call to InitializeComponent. Don't forget to add it to `this.Components` to make sure it is Disposed

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a paint event on every tick of the timer.  That calls multiple paint events and slows everything down, especially when you are scrolling.

Move the paint subscription to the constructor.  Also, declare the timer at the form level so it can be properly disposed when the form closes.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

public AllOrders()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.RowPrePaint += dataGridView1_RowPrePaint;

  timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
  timer1.Interval = 10000;
  timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
  timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: OK.  I removed the process from the tick event, moved the paint process to just below the INITIALIZE, added the timer stuff just below that.
The data on the screen still does not update. Not even when I scroll to the bottom.  It only updates when I click the "update" button.
What event is triggered when the interval is met?  How does it know to get new data and refresh the screen if I don't tell it to?

Comment: @Cathy Is your `timer1_tick` still calling `Get_Data()`?  Are you waiting the 10 seconds to see if it fires?

Comment: Yes, the only call for Get_Data() is in the form load and the button click.
I left it running for 10 minutes.  When nothing happened, I scrolled down to see if it would update.  When it still didn't, I clicked the button.  Then it updated.

Comment: @Cathy `the only call for Get_Data() is in the form load and the button click.`  Shouldn't that also be in the timer tick?  What do you want the timer to do?

Comment: I had it in the timer tick.  You said it was executing the Get_Data every time it ticked so I took it out. I guess I'm confused what a timer tick does and what purpose the interval serves.
Does the timer tick mean it executes the timer tick event every millisecond?  I would think I need to check the number of ticks against the interval and if it equals, then execute Get_Data().

Comment: @Cathy Confusing post.  Your question was about a timer and getting data.  Maybe take a step back. A timer is just something that runs at an interval.  Do you need that?  If not, then get rid of it.  Your code had 10,000 ms for an interval.  That's 10 seconds.  It really sounds like you don't need a timer.  Getting the data when the form loads should be good enough in most circumstances.  Your timer would only be necessary if it is critical to poll for changes that are happening on the database that your form isn't aware of.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear.  Its a dashboard that gets data from an Excel spreadsheet file that is updated every 10 minutes.  I put an update button in just so I'd have a way manually update it if I wanted to.  But it does need a way to update the datagridview every 10 minutes without a human telling it to.  If theres a way other than a timer to do that, please let me know.

Comment: @Cathy No, a timer will work.  The essence of my answer was to remove the line `dataGridView1.RowPrePaint += dataGridView1_RowPrePaint;` from your `Get_Data()` routine.  That line of code "adds" painting events every time it's called, and you don't want that.  You should only subscribe to events once, which is why I moved that line to the constructor.  The grid will call that paint code on demand when it needs to.

Comment: OK.  So does the timer1_tick event happen every millisecond?

Comment: @Cathy Your code has `timer1.Interval = 10000;`, so that's 10,000 milliseconds, or 10 seconds.  So the timer1_tick event happens every 10 seconds.  If you change the Interval to 5000, the timer1_tick event will happen every 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm still at my original problem.  Either the Get_Data isn't executing every x minutes like its supposed to because its in the timer1_tick event and the interval is set.  Or it is executing and the screen just isn't updating.